# What does "bond sale" mean in this article?

Tags: meaning

In http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-06-01/new-york-university-bond-sale-shows-hype-over-stem-in-city-real, what does  "bond sale" mean?

Does bond mean the same as the thing we can buy for investment?

Comment: As I realized "bond" here means:  [  count  ] finance : an official document in which a government or company promises to pay back an amount of money that it has borrowed and to pay interest for the borrowed money ( source Webster's dictionary). They sell bonds to raise money for their project.

Comment: Why did the dictionary not help you? Can you explain a bit more why you think it might not mean the "thing we can buy for investment"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these are the same bonds you (or anybody else) can buy as investments; but the 'sale' which the article refers to is not the ordinary everyday trade in bonds on the public markets but the original issue of the bonds by an organization seeking to borrow capital.

A bond is, at bottom, an IOU for a loan: it's a promise by the issuer to pay the bond's holder so-and-so much at such-and-such a time in the future in return for present use of the amount the holder lends the issuer. This story reports that NYU issued bonds—promises to pay—to borrow $832 million for various STEM projects. The people who bought those bonds may subsequently re-sell them on the bond markets to investors like you and me, which gives us the right to receive NYU's repayment.